# Why only one PC is not updating the GPO?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

Recently I migrated my print server from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2. I deployed the printers through, printer(right click) -> Deploy with GP -> Default Domain Policy(per machine). All the PCs in the domain shows the printers form the new server except one PC. It is a Windows 7 Professional SP1 PC. At first the error on the  PC was  that it is  missing the RSOP. So I started the Netlogon service which was stopped/manual for some reason. And now when I `gpupdate /force` the PC, it shows the below error:

```
Updating Policy...

User Policy update has completed successfully.
Computer Policy update has completed successfully.

The following warnings were encountered during computer policy processing:

Windows failed to apply the Deployed Printer Connections settings. Deployed Printer Connections settings might have its own log file. Please click on the "More information" link.

For more detailed information, review the event log or run GPRESULT /H GPReport.html from the command line to access information about Group Policy results.
```

Now I tried other users on this PC and same result. So the problem can be narrowed down to only the PC.

GP Debug log(gpsvc.log) [here](http://pastebin.com/jEV9Z3GL)

event log info [here](http://pastebin.com/1Str563K)

GP results of the computer given below:[image: here]
Now the 'policy events' tab on that time stamp shows the info:`Security policy in the Group policy objects has been applied successfully.`

Resultant Set of policy(mmc -> add/remove snap-ins -> resultant set of policy) on the PC shows the below error:[image]

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Try resetting the cached gpo, you can simply remove the pc from the domain & readd it for that purpose

Comment: @yagmoth555 that didn't do the trick. I deleted, [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft] [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft] [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects] [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies -->  Reboot.

Which got rid of the gpupdate issue. Currently printers from both servers are displayed and I cannot remove the old one(access denied issue). Access denied issue was there from the begining; tried even as local administrator with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my winning policy for printer deployment was computer policy(which is not even enabled) not 'default domain policy'. So here is what I did,

> I deleted(backup everything please),
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft]
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft]
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group
>   Policy Objects]
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
>
> Reboot.

Now the `gpupdate /force` successfully finishes and new printers are displayed. The problem is I cannot remove the old printers, it is showing "Access denied, unable to remove device" even as local administrator.

will update after fixing the last issue.

Comment: my tip worked then ? :) for the printer that dont want to be removed there is a fixit from ms that remove all lost printer (lost as usually it happen when the printer can retrieve the share)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this registry entry on a test pc (backup regedit first):

Registry Loccation: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers\PointAndPrint

(if it is not there- create new KEY)

DWord:  `RestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators`

Value: 0

Then restart the test pc and preform `gpupdate /force`